# Get html source code with cURL in salesforce

Tags: apex, rest, curl

Is there any way to get html source code of external url using cUrl or rest api. As in php we can get by using following code.

```
$ch = curl_init("http://www.example-webpage.com/file.html");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Can we achieve something like this in Apex ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: See Apex's [HTTP Classes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http.htm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the simplest sense, yes you can. You can use the example verbatim from the HTTP classes documentation to send a GET request and return the HTML source as a string.

```
public class HttpCalloutSample {

  // Pass in the endpoint to be used using the string url
  public String getCalloutResponseContents(String url) {

    // Instantiate a new http object
    Http h = new Http();

     // Instantiate a new HTTP request, specify the method (GET) as well as the endpoint
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint(url);
    req.setMethod('GET');

    // Send the request, and return a response
    HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
    return res.getBody();
  }
}
```

There are a couple of additional points you need to consider:

1. You can't make callouts to arbitrary URLs from Salesforce. The domains need to first be configured as trusted under the **Remote Site Settings**.
2. Not all contexts support making callouts. For instance, you can't make a callout directly in a Trigger. If you need to the process to start from a trigger you would first need to transition to an asynchronous context.